# Один объект на две формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Существует способ, с помощью которого можно разместить один и тот же объект на 2 формы?

А доступ организовать, например, по статической ссылке, которая будет создана в отдельном классе, или что-то подобное?

Comment: Да, и Вы его только что описали.

Comment: @Igor если я напишу тупо `Form2.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);`, то он пропадёт с основной формы и появится во второй.

Comment: Вот видите, Ваш вопрос уже начал улучшаться (только надо убрать слово "тупо").

Comment: _Графический компонент_ (`Control`) может быть только на одной форме одновременно. Вы не с той стороны заходите. Нужно создать модель, содержащую некое значение и привязать её (data binding) к _двум разным_ контролам на формах.

Comment: Что именно за объект?

Comment: @D.Stark `textBox` и `comboBox`

Comment: А с какой целью вам понадобилось их "связать" с другой формой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Графический компонент (`Control`) может быть только на одной форме одновременно.

Вы не с той стороны заходите. Нужно создать модель, содержащую некое значение и привязать её (data binding) к двум разным контролам на формах.

Допустим, имеется следующая модель:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Имеются две формы. На каждой есть свой `TextBox`. Назовём их, соответственно, `textBoxOnFormOne` и `textBoxOnFormTwo`

На первой форме создаём объект нашего класса модели:

```
foo = new Foo();
```

И привязываем его к текстбоксу:

```
textBoxOnFormOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", foo, "Bar", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Тем или иным образом передаём ссылку на объект во вторую форму. И в ней тоже делаем аналогичную привязку:

```
textBoxOnFormTwo.DataBindings.Add("Text", foo, "Bar", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Теперь, если вводить/изменять значение в текстбоксе на одной форме, оно будет автоматически изменяться на другой.